# Ajax In QueryMethod Calling in Classic Asp For Email sending

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I am Having Problem in getting AJAX Method in JQUERY To Post on my Classic ASP Page Method to send email.
Here is my Code Please Tell me what mistake i'm doing.
Also Suggest me how to Redirect to previous html page after the execution of my ap page function.

```
             function QuickEmail() {            
             $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "emailsending.asp",
            data: '{FirstName: "' + $("#txtFirstName").val() + '",LastName:"' +        
            $("#txtLastName").val() + '",Email:"' 
            + $("#txtEmail").val() + '",ContactNo:"' + $("#txtContactNo").val() + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,                                
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
        $.unblockUI();    
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {

        $.msgBox({ title: "Message Sent!", content: "Message has been sent successfully.", type: "info" });
    }
```

Here is my ASP Page

```
enter code here
          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>
    <title></title>
      </head>
        <body>
     <%
       dim FirstName
       dim LastName
       dim EmailAdd
       dim Contact
       FirstName = Request("txtFirstName")
       LastName = Request("txtLastName")
       EmailAdd = Request("txtEmail")
       Contact = Request("txtContactNo")
       Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="xxxxxx@gmail.com" 'You can also use you email address that's setup through google apps.
       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="xxxxxxxx"

       Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update

       Mail.Subject= FirstName
       Mail.From= "xxxxxx@gmail.com" 
       Mail.To=EmailAdd
       Mail.TextBody=FirstName & vbCrLf & LastName & vbCrLf & Contact & vbCrLf &   EmailAdd
      Mail.Send
      Set Mail = Nothing
      Response.Redirect("index.html") 
      %>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: if you want to redirect to previous page you can easily do that via JS: `history.back`. the other possiblity would be `response.redirect`.
furthermore: do you get any errors, what exactly is the problem? we don't know what is wrong so we can't help you. last but not least: welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't get any error it's just that the mail is not sending  to desired address.AND history.back  has worked for me. thanks.

Comment: have you got some example data? are you 100% sure the email get's passed in correctly? please provide expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0):

You pass your data in this way:

```
data: '{FirstName: "' + $("#txtFirstName").val()
      + '",LastName:"' + $("#txtLastName").val() 
      + '",Email:"' + $("#txtEmail").val() 
      + '",ContactNo:"' + $("#txtContactNo").val() + '"}',
```

when you now access you data with the form-identities, you will recieve possibly malformed or `null` data.

Instead try either:

- changing the data attributes you sent (Email --> txtEmail)
- changing the request statements you got (request("txtEmail") --> request("Email"))
- send your form instead of manually parsed JSON-Data: that would look like this

  data: document.forms.quickmail.data,